# Apache PHP out of the box caching

Tags: apache-2.2, php, cache

What is a recommended strategy from caching PHP dynamic pages? I have tried a couple of suggestions from serverfault, but they all include code changes. I was wondering if someone has been able to get this to work? (php dynamic page caching)
And I see this has been asked many times over. But is there actually one that works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a reverse proxy like [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/).

I still doubt that you're going to get away with zero code changes, though.

Answer (score 1):

To cache the entire page nginx and/or varnish should do the trick.

To cache PHP code, then look into using APC or similar.

Anything else and you will definitely have to make some code changes.

Answer (score 0):

If your dynamic pages are actually the same no matter who the end user might be, then putting something like Varnish on port 80 caching requests from Apache on port 8080, is probably the simplest way to do this and does not require any code changes.

If your dynamic pages are different for different users, then you will definitely need to perform some code changes, unless the application already sets cache/do-not-cache headers which you can tell Varnish to respect.